# Google Analytics' push not received on Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-commerce

I've read a lot of people having this problem on tracking orders' event on Drupal Commerce site, but I didn't find any convincing reply according to my context. That's why I'm asking here for help.

First of all, here's what I can say about the context i'm working on :

- Drupal 7.43 with Drupal Commerce
- GA, Commerce GA, and GA Push modules are installed
- I can receive tracking datas from visits, pages viewed, etc
- For commerce tracking, I tried the 4 sending methods (JS, SSGA PHP, UTMP PHP, UTMP JS), and none of it worked
- The Rule triggered for sending data to GA is working (I tried adding an email sending to the Rule, and I received it)
- If I manually type this script, I can see data on GA :

(in Chrome's Developer Tools)

```
_gaq.push(["_addTrans", "578", "Patrick Frey", "56", "0", "0", "Paris", "", "France"]);
_gaq.push(["_addItem", "578", "130", "Test", "No category", "10", "1.00"]);
_gaq.push(["_addItem", "578", "shipping", "Free shipping", "No category", "0", "1.00"]);
_gaq.push(["_trackTrans"]);
```

Is someone have an idea of what's going on with my GA Pushs ? I'm working on a production site so I can't really try, but if someone have an idea of how i could debug this, this would be great !

Thanks,

Tristan

Comment: Just to be certain, you are using classic GA and not UA?

Comment: Do you got any error JS on console ?

Comment: Hm how can I verify if I use classic GA or UA ? I have an id like UA-XXXXXXXX-X for tracking basic events, and I include my script from http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js, if it can determine which one I use...

Comment: I don't want to do many fake orders, because it will change stats on Google Analytics, and it seems to be impossible to remove data from statistics, so I can't verify if I get any error JS after the order.